# Placement of Close Button on DIV using CSS

Tags: css, html

I am trying to set the position of a close button over a div and cant get it to the top right hand side. I have read many of the Stack articles relating to this but cant get this working.

Is anyone able to assist?

**http://jsfiddle.net/grantfeldman/K4p6g/1**

```
<div class="tag">
    <a class="closeButton"></a>
    Foo
</div>

div.tag
{
    color: #EEE;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #324566;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #283957;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.closeButton
{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://cdn-sg1.pgimgs.com/images/pg/close-button.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/K4p6g/2/

Needed changes:

```
#divMyTags div.existingTag
{
    position: relative;
}

.closeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
}
```

This absolutely positions the close button relative to its parent.

**Quick update** for another requirement in your comment:
http://jsfiddle.net/K4p6g/5/

Note that it's a quick update using jQuery, but it should give you the idea. If you're already using jQuery in your project then you're good with this.

Comment: awesome thanks very much. final question - is there an easy way to make them hidden until hover/mouseover?

Answer (score 1):

I just changed some things, have a look

```
#divMyTags div.existingTag
{
    color: #EEE;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #324566;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #283957;
    **padding: 0px**;
    margin: 5px;
}
**#divMyTags .theText
{
    margin:10px;
}**
```

Updated sources here : http://jsfiddle.net/K4p6g/4/